# How to iterate through a dictionary, loading the next item with button press in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, dictionary

I am making an app that will ask a series of questions, giving a value when answering yes or no. I have an initial view controller with a collection view of question types. This view controller passes the type information to a new view controller with the question layout (image, label, buttons). On the second view controller I have a switch/case statement to provide the proper dictionary results for the type that was passed in (via questionTypeReceived), populating the initial view correctly. Once you answer the question (simple yes or no) I want to update with the next question. Any advice to get this done?

Extra info: I have the questions view controller (referred to here as secondary VC) refactored because I initially thought I wanted to reuse it, not just reload it. All aspects work **EXCEPT** the reloading with the next question... Yes, that is because I don't have the code in there to do that. I have been trying different for loops in different places but keep getting errors so I go back to the current setup because there are no errors

**Initial VC**

```
    let names = [ "Work", "School", "Family", "Friends", "Random" ]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        questionType = names[indexPath.row] as String
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "questions", bundle: nil)
        let questionsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "questionsViewController") as! questionsViewController
        questionsVC.questionTypeReceived = questionType
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(questionsVC, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "question_segue", sender: questionType)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let dest = segue.destination as? questionsViewController else {
            print("Can't perform downcast")
            return
        }
        dest.questionTypeReceived = questionType
    }
```

**secondary VC**

```
    var questionTypeReceived:String = String()
    var answerTotalValue:Double = Double()
    var questionNumber:Int = Int()
    var questionBody = ""
    var questionType = ""

    let answerYesValue:Double = Double.random(in: 1...5)
    let answerNoValue:Double = Double.random(in: 0..<3)

        switch questionTypeReceived {

        case "Random":
            questionTypeReceived = "Random"
            questionsImageView.image = UIImage(named: randomImages.randomElement()!)
            let questionNumber = randomQuestions.keys.sorted()
            let questionBody = randomQuestions.values
            for (questionNumber, questionBody) in randomQuestions {
                questionTitleLabel.text = "Question #\(questionNumber)"
                questionsTextLabel.text = questionBody
            }
        default: return
        }

    let randomQuestions: [Int : String] = [
        1: "Did you already agree to attend?",
        2: "Does it cost money to attend?",
        3: "Is it time consuming (4+ hours)?"
    ]

    @IBAction func yesButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        answerTotalValue += answerYesValue
        print(answerTotalValue)
        print(questionTypeReceived)
    }
```

Comment: Where is the “dictionary”?

Comment: I may not have used the correct term, when I say "dictionary", I am referring to the  "let randomQuestions: [Int : String] = ...." line. There are 5 types, I didn't want to overload with code.

Comment: OK, good answer, that's a dictionary. But you cannot cycle through that in the way you expect, because a dictionary has no order. You have _written_ it in a certain order, but there is no way you're going to retrieve the elements in that order. Basically you've chosen a structure that prevents doing what you want to do, I think.

Comment: I have the keys being sorted, I was thinking by doing that I can refer to the sorted variable, and display the value for the current key. Is that not possible either?

Comment: Yes, you can sort on the keys, but that is not what you are doing in your code. What you are doing is declaring two variables, `questionNumber` and `questionBody`, and then throwing them away and trying to cycle thru your dictionary — in, as I said, random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion on how to handle properties and local variables, you have for instance 1 property and 2 local variables named `questionNumber` and you are also iterating the whole dictionary when as I see it you only want one question.

One way to get away from this and a solution that is also good for other reason like not doing everything in your controller class and separating responsibilities is to move the questions and handling of them into a separate struct or class.

Let's create a `Questions` struct that holds the questions, keeps track of what questions has been asked and can deliver the next question to ask.

```
struct Questions {
    private randomQuestions: [Int : String] = [
        1: "Did you already agree to attend?",
        2: "Does it cost money to attend?",
        3: "Is it time consuming (4+ hours)?"
    ]

    private var questionIndex = 0

    mutating func nextQuestion() -> (number: Int, question: String?) {
        questionIndex += 1
        return (questionIndex, randomQuestions[questionIndex])
    }
}
```

Note the question mark for the string in the return tuple, if no questions exists for a index (questionIndex > 3) the question returned will be nil

Then you can use it in you code like this, first declare it as a property in your VC

```
var questions = Questions()
```

Then when getting the question

```
switch questionTypeReceived {
case "Random":
    questionsImageView.image = UIImage(named: randomImages.randomElement()!)
    let nextQuestion = question.nextQuestion()
    if let question = nextQuestion.question {
        questionTitleLabel.text = "Question #\(nextQuestion.number)"
        questionsTextLabel.text = question
    } else {
       // no more questions to ask, this needs to be handled
    }
default: return
}
```

So a little more work to write a new struct but your code in the VC becomes simpler and a lot of properties and variables are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Joakim, this is enabling me to cycle through the questions.. Needs a few tweaks to get to what I need but this is the core I needed to build on.. Thank you again!